# Updating Entry and Label widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

i have defined a GUI class that creates a tkinter window with a couple of entries. I would like that every time that the user overwrites the Entries and press Enter, there is some operation done in the background. In addition, i would like that the entries are checking regularly certain values and updating them, so the user could see if they changed; In the example below i use a static dictionary, but normally those parameters are obtained from a camera and could fluctuate.

However, i am not even able to get the correct value printed in the label. I am not a tkinter expert so any idea would be appreciated

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI():
    
    
    def __init__(self, window, window_title,input_dict):

        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
        self.window.geometry('400x200')

        top_frame = Frame(self.window)
        top_frame.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
        
        Label(top_frame, text="Frame rate (fps)").grid(row=0)
        Label(top_frame, text="Exposure time (ms)").grid(row=2)
        
        self.labeling=Label(top_frame, text="Result").grid(row=3)
        
        self.e1_var = StringVar() # or StringVar(top) 

        self.e1_var.set(str(round(input_dict['frameRate'])))
        
        self.e2_var = StringVar() # or StringVar(top) 
        # print(type(self.e2_var))

        self.e2_var.set(str(round(input_dict['Exp_time'])))

        self.fps_entry = Entry(top_frame,textvariable=self.e1_var)
        self.exptime_entry = Entry(top_frame,textvariable=self.e2_var)     
        self.fps_entry.bind("<Return>",self.my_tracer)
        self.exptime_entry.bind("<Return>",self.my_tracer)
        

        self.fps_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.exptime_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
     
        self.window.mainloop()

    
    def my_tracer(self,event):
        
        val1=int(self.e1_var.get())
        val2=int(self.e2_var.get())
        
        self.labeling.configure(text=str(val1*val2))        
            
input_dict = {
        'frameRate':  50,
        'Exp_time':  5000}
    
video_object=GUI(Tk(),"Test",input_dict)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: to run function periodically in `tkinter` you can use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` and this function would have to run again `root.after(...)` to run itself again.

Answer (score 2):

The error your code produces is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'`, right?

Look at this line:

```
self.labeling=Label(top_frame, text="Result").grid(row=3)
```

`self.labeling` will be `None` because `grid()` returns None. It is indeed bad practice to 'chain' a geometry manager to the creation of a widget. Change to:

```
self.labeling=Label(top_frame, text="Result")
self.labeling.grid(row=3)
```

Now the labels are updating when the user enters a new value.

Comment: yes indeed, I tried to avoid that in the other labels, not sure why I oversaw this one. My problem is that I would like to continuously display in the Entries certain values ( I connect to a camera and get both fps and exposure time in real-time, maybe asking every second using .after()) and when the user changes the value, it communicates to the camera, and after keeps refreshing and showing the values in the same entries, do you think this could work or one action would interact somehow with each other?